# Could not find colorpicker-0.0.13.aar (com.github.QuadFlask:colorpicker:0.0.13)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, jitpack

Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find colorpicker-0.0.13.aar (com.github.QuadFlask:colorpicker:0.0.13).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://jitpack.io/com/github/QuadFlask/colorpicker/0.0.13/colorpicker-0.0.13.aar

Possible solution:

- Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html

build.gradle (app)

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }

    }



dependencies {
implementation 'com.github.QuadFlask:colorpicker:0.0.13'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add following in your top level build.gradle file

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

And then add following dependency in app level dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.QuadFlask:colorpicker:0.0.15'
}
```

Comment: upgrading dependency to .15 solved for me on Android Studio 4.2 C15